# Debian (PIXEL) in VirtualBox won't save files with persistence

Tags: virtualbox, raspbian, debian-installer, persistence

I just downloaded the ISO for Raspbian (Jessie Pixel) to use on a PC and not a Pi. I decided to try it on VirtualBox (Windows 7) first and I noticed that even when I run it with persistence, it doesn't save any of the files I have created after a reboot. I've tried creating with .vdi and .vmdk and no luck. Any ideas how to get around this?

What I'm trying to do is (make an older PC a kiosk) run "raspi-config", but I get an error saying boot partition isn't mounted. What I'm thinking is maybe if I can get persistence to work I can try and create a boot partition in VBox... if that's even possible.

[image]

Comment: But raspbian is an ARM based distribution, and your PC probably is not(Intel derivate). It will NEVER work...

Comment: Are you trying to run the installation disk or the installed version?  I guess it's probably just the installation disk which most likely uses SquashFS for storage, which isn't persistent.

Comment: @nwildner that's what I thought until I came across https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pixel-pc-mac/

Comment: @JuliePelletier It says it's a live version and nothing about being able to install, which is why I'm trying to understand why it won't save files. I'm not entirely sure what SquashFS is, but I'll take a look into that thanks.

Comment: @ShaadShaad:  You would probably be much better off installing it on your virtual drive than customizing the live drive.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yea I would love to, but it doesn't give me an install option.

Comment: @nwildner Sorry you are absolutely correct. I got confused when I saw Jessie and Pixel on the Rpi webiste... just assumed it was Raspbian for a PC. I'll try and change my title because now that is wrong!

Comment: Pixel, that is the graphic interface is multiplatform. The raspbian distribution is not. :)

Answer (score 0):

At this [(Link)](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/rpi-pixel-virtualbox), they explain how to make a VM with pixel running from a CD image and saving the persistence data into a new HD virtual unit.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it [would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.